# What is the translation of this nameplate?

Tags: translation

I'm in a need of this product and I can't seem to find what this nameplate means anywhere. I'm looking for a name of the manufacturer or something that point me to that.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Asking for a translation without providing your attempts is against site policy: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic ... "[ ... ] asking for a translation of a word or passage without showing previous effort are not allowed." **Solution:** "We are happy to assist with your translation questions if you are having a specific problem. Please show your attempt at translation in your question and state which area you are having difficulty with."

Comment: I'm sorry if I've violated anything. I have only posted here because I could not find the answer anywhere else.

Comment: 卸荷阀 iciba： unloader ； unloader valve ； unloading valve also see Internet

Comment: @S.Rhee Thank You. I was hoping to get the manufacturer's name. But I guess I have to look further !

Answer (score 1):

It's "卸荷阀" in Chinese. It means "Unloading Valve". There's no manufacturer information on your picture. Perhaps you can search 卸荷阀 on taobao.com to find more clues.